# Windows Script Issue - Works line by line, not as run.cmd

Tags: command-line

The following lines of code work perfectly for what I am wanting to do if I copy/past into CMD/DOS one line at a time. However, if I put all the code into a run.cmd file and run the file, it appears that the code stops executing after the second statement which creates a file called HEADER.txt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
copy *.txt MARD.txt

echo HEADERSTRING > HEADER.txt


findstr /v "HEADERSTRING" MARD.txt > MARDGOOD.txt

copy HEADER.txt+MARDGOOD.txt

del MARD.tx
del MARDGOOD.txt

rename HEADER.txt MARD.txt
```

Comment: Since this is a cmd, You might want to add a @echo on at the start of the script and see if you get an explicit error messages displayed.

Comment: Try use grep from [UnxUpdates.zip](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/). Syntax something like : grep -v "HEADERSTRING" MARD.txt > MARDGOOD.txt

Comment: Are you really saying `HEADERSTRING`, or are you using that as a placeholder for your real header string? Does it have any non-alphanumeric characters in it, like `%` or `&`?

Comment: @G-Man HEADERSTRING is just a place holder for readability sake on here. The actual header of the file is big and ugly. This particular header does not have any non-alphanumeric characters. Other files I am trying to use this solution on do. I have a header that has the "/" character which I think is causing me some issues.